# Need to get the last worksheet name in msgbox

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get the last (rightmost worksheet) name in msgbox.

I used Sheets(Sheets.Count) to get last sheet. But its only giving first sheets name. Kindly help me on this.

Here is my code.

```
Sub ShowMRNumber()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("location")
Set xlSheet = xlApp.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

MsgBox "MR No. is" & vbNewLine xlSheet.Name
xlApp.Workbooks.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application` is a trouble-maker. Unless you take care to quit the instance you are creating with this line you will have a new instance of Excel every time you run this code. Add `xlApp.Quit` to your sub.

Answer (score 1):

Your line saying

```
Set xlSheet = xlApp.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

should actually be

```
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(xlBook.Sheets.Count)
```

---

Using `xlApp.Sheets` is probably not an issue, as that would probably have defaulted to the active workbook within the `xlApp` instance of Excel, but `Sheets.Count` (without a `xlApp` or `xlBook` qualifier) would not have been referring to a workbook open in a different instance of Excel - it would have been referring to the active workbook in the instance of Excel where the code was running.